Insufficient Privilege error when deleting a Case as an Admin
I am a standard System Administrator in a sandbox and I have found very old Case records owned by a Sites user that I cannot access through the UI or delete. I can query them.
Trying to open the records loads the "Insufficient Privileges" error page and trying to delete any of them (using external tools) results in INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY: insufficient access rights on object id [].
How can these be removed from my system?
Note: I have full access to everything else in the system, including other Cases.  These Cases are not in the recycle bin.

do you have permissions on the Case parent (lookup) records - notably Account and Contact?

@cropredy Yes, I do.  No issues there.

just checking, in your query, you are not including deleted records?

@cropredy I tried both with and without deleted records included and the records are returned with both operations.

Does your user have View All Data / Modify All  Data permissions?

@cropredy Yes.  I'm on the standard Sys Amin profile so those permissions are locked on it.

Enumerate all the lookup fields on Contact and verify you have CRUD permissions on all of the related parent objects as well as read permissions on the specific records that are parents of the Case.

@cropredy I hit the select all boxes for Read and Edit on Case and Account for my profile (System Admin).  Still no luck.

if you login as the Sites user, can you see the Case in the UX?

@cropredy Thanks for your suggestions but I ended up opening a ticket with SF support.  They were also stumped by the issue and will likely have to get the backend team to delete the records directly due to some sort of dangling reference that we have no control over.

There was nothing I could do and Salesforce support had to run a tool on the data to make it available. They confirmed it was a bug on their end.
